# How to apply animation in WPF for custom class?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 3d

I am developing .NET application that is using SharpDX (DirectX wrapper for C#). Additionally I am implementing WPF interface (in XAML). Let's say, that I want to define rotation angle of particular 3D model in my app:

```
<dx3d:DxGeometryModel3D.Transform>
    <dx3d:DxTransform3DGroup>
        <dx3d:DxTransform3DGroup.Children>                                
            <dx3d:DxRotateTransform3D>
                <dx3d:DxRotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="30" />
                </dx3d:DxRotateTransform3D.Rotation>
            </dx3d:DxRotateTransform3D>                         
        </dx3d:DxTransform3DGroup.Children>
    </dx3d:DxTransform3DGroup>
</dx3d:DxGeometryModel3D.Transform>
```

As you can see, I have my own classes (DxGeometryModel3D instead of GeometryModel3D from WPF) and inside, I created dependency properties that are more commonly used. Now, I want to **create simple animation**, that will change the Angle property. In WPF it is like below (and I want to do it in the similar way):

```
<AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="30">
    <AxisAngleRotation3D.Triggers>
        // animation defined here
    </AxisAngleRotation3D.Triggers>
</AxisAngleRotation3D>
```

In other words: How can I attach to my class Triggers property?

Comment: I'm going to make a wild guess here, but If your Custom classes inherit `UIElement`, then you should be able to use triggers directly

Comment: @MarioStoilov my custom classes are inheriting from DependencyObject

Comment: try this article -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725477%28v=expression.40%29.aspx I think it shows how to add a custom trigger to a DependencyObject

Comment: @MarioStoilov thanks, but I think I will need to know how to add trigger to custom class, not otherwise ;)

Comment: Well since your class inherits DependencyObject this **should** work. Other than that I have no ideas :/

Comment: @MarioStoilov unfortunately not. But when it iherits from FrameworkElement, then Triggers property is accessible. Although I think I should replace my AxisAngleRotation3D (which came from WPF) by my custom class that inherits from FrameworkElement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MarioStoilov hinted in his comment, your custom class does *not* have a `Triggers` property. This is because the familiar `Triggers` property is *not* defined in the `DependencyObject` class that your class currently extends. The simplest way to add this property (that will work as expected) would be for you to extend the `FrameworkElement` Class which defines this property, instead of the `DependencyObject` class (and not the `UIElement` class either @MarioStoilov).

You can find out more about the `FrameworkElement` Class from the [`FrameworkElement` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: I came into the same conclusion. I should replace AxisAngleRotation (because animation is going to change properties on this element) to new custom class that inherits from FrameworkElement. Thanks you both!